# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification using firebase

Tags: android

so i recently added the firebase database dependencies to my gradle and i got this message after sync

> 'all com.android.support libraries must use the same exact version
>   specification(mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0-rc02, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc02 and
>   com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

what changes should i make to stop getting this error message?

Answer (score 0):

**JUST A SUGGESTION**

I suggest, for now, you should use `v7:27` instead of `v7:28`. As there are many unanswered questions about this version. I too fallback to previous version, and until it is stable then, you can update it.

So you can try this:

Change your `sdkVersion` to 27

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {

        targetSdkVersion 27
    }


 ...

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: it fails to sycn and gives me the error message `Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.3.` and draws a red line on everything with 27.1.1

Comment: it fails to sync and gives this error message `Module 'app': platform 'android-27' not found.`

Comment: Is not found because you have not updated your sdk for that version. Goto sdk manager to do download and install API 27. which android 8.1 (Oreo) API level 27

Comment: Also, see my updated answer. I removed the buildToolsVersion.